# Bind to a copy of database data in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

Let me preface: I'm asking this because I'm not sure how to start. I know MVVM, WPF, ... but I am lacking the general idea here.

The idea is to develop an app for inhouse use which takes a subset of data from a database and then makes an in-memory copy. The user will work on that data, modify some values, maybe add and/or delete some rows and when he's done, the data shall be stored back in the database.

What would be a keyword I need to look into how to do this efficiently. Is there some design pattern I might be interested in?

Comment: Sounds like you need an ORM such as Entity Framework Core or NHibernate,

Comment: You are describing the most common use case of a database. There are plenty example for every common DBS. The moment you populate data models with data you are creating a copy. Then when done you update the database. How reading/writing from/to your database exactly looks like depends on the framework you are using. You never work directly on database data. Every database system has an extra layer that actually enables the client to have full control how and when to execute transactions.

Comment: See [Microsoft Docs: Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

Comment: I‘m quite familiar with EF and LINQ. Even with SQL. The question was more pointing into the direction if there were any design patterns I can use with my problem. See the answer below.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make sense. If you know EF that well you should understand that it does anything you asked for. Not sure what design pattern you expect. Again, your "problem" is really trivial. It's just basics. Read data, edit/create/delete data, write data. If you are familiar with EF then you just have done it a dozend times. I really don't see your problem. Meant you have to be more specific. Your question is very broad. When you know how to operate on a database sand use EF already then your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some random thoughts:

The first thing I would worry about in this case is appropriately locking the data being worked on, because it sounds like the user will spend some time editing the in-memory copy. This might not be necessary in your context.

As for tracking/committing the changes, you could store a queue of Commands that represents the operations on the data. Each command then translates to a query to execute on the db.
If you are using EF Core or EF6 you can simply query the data you need and then re-attach each entity in the modified or deleted state. (Don't keep long-lived DbContexts).

You could even save a copy of the original data and only evaluate the changes at the end.

Having a chatty system that commits every change immediately could also work if you keep track of old values and your network or DBMS aren't congested.

Comment: Thank you, excellent input. Concurrency might really be an issue. I‘ll have to take that into account. I think I won‘t have to deal with the actions sequence. The main task is to modify the data and add some stuff so it can be fed into a different system later. The only point in time where the actual state must be frozen is when the data is considered finished.

Comment: Thank you for the input on attaching data, I‘ll need to read up on this.